# Avoid code duplication if what changes is one argument type only

Tags: go, refactoring, code-duplication

As you can see these functions differ only in `keys []int` and `keys []*int` (and in name).

```golang
func (db *myDB) QueryWithKeys(keys []int) ([]*models.Player) {
    var players = make([]*models.Player, len(keys))
  _ := db.Model(&players).Where("id in (?)", pg.In(keys)).Select()
  // several other equal code here
    return players
}

func (db *myDB) QueryWithPointerKeys(keys []*int) ([]*models.Player) {
    var players = make([]*models.Player, len(keys))
    _ := db.Model(&players).Where("id in (?)", pg.In(keys)).Select()
  // several other equal code here
    return players
}
```

**Is there a way to avoid this code duplication?**

Comment: Should It be resolved by changing the argument to []interface{} instead of []int or []*int?

Comment: *"Is there a way to avoid this code duplication?"* Yes, pass the `keys` as `interface{}` and also provide the `len` at the call site. i.e. `func (db *myDB) QueryWithKeys(keys interface{}, length int) ...`, and then `db.QueryWithKeys(keys, len(keys))`.

Comment: @mkopriva why not `[]interface{}`?

Comment: @FredHors Because `[]interface{}` is a "concrete" type, and if you have `[]*int` or `[]int` and you want to pass those as `[]interface{}` you first would need to manually convert them. On the other hand `interface{}` is an interface type, implicitly implemented by every type in go, including `[]*int` and `[]int`, so no manual conversion necessary. Plus `interface{}` is also the type of the `pg.In` function. In short, using `[]interface{}` will require more code thereby increasing the complexity without any real benefit.

Comment: @mkopriva, understood. Please answer me so I can accept it. Thanks for your commitment. Really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can re-define the method to accept a `keys` argument of type `interface{}` and also a `length` argument of type `int` indicating the number of elements in the underlying slice of the `keys` argument, this length would be provided by the caller.

```
func (db *myDB) QueryWithKeys(keys interface{}, length int) ([]*models.Player) {
    var players = make([]*models.Player, length)
    _ := db.Model(&players).Where("id in (?)", pg.In(keys)).Select()
    // several other equal code here
    return players
}
```

With that you can then use it like so:

```
var keys []int = // get list of integers from wherever
players := db.QueryWithKeys(keys, len(keys))

var keys2 []*int = // get list of integer pointers from wherever
players2 := db.QueryWithKeys(keys2, len(keys2))
```

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is making the QueryWithKeys method call the QueryWithPointerKeys method and just put in a a pointer to the keys integer. The obvious disadvantage is that it will take a little longer to proccess.

Comment: An example please?